# Should we unit test a method which stores a value in a database and returns nothing?

Tags: database, unit-testing

I have one method which stores some value in to the row set and then these values update in the database in caller method.
Is it good practice to put it under system test?

```
updateStatus(documents) {
    Iterate over the documents {
        Row row=rowset.egtRow(index);
        update the status in row.
    }
}
```

Comment: My general mantra is “If something can go wrong, you should test it”. However, your question has too few details as that one could write a more substantial answer.  Could you [edit] the question to add a description of your function, for example with pseudo-code? Are you using some ORM or does the function include a raw SQL string?

Comment: Yes, unless you never need to access said value - then you don't need the function.

Comment: At what phase of testing?

Comment: Your 1-word edit change your question significantly. You should definitely test your method with an actual database underneath in your integration tests. As for unit tests, the contract of your unit is that when you call your method, something is saved in the database. If you can mock your database access object, then you can verify it was called correctly. Personnally, if there is no validation logic and it simply do a call to save something in the database, I only test it in integration tests.

Comment: Yes, this method consist of logic which populates the row set object to update in database in another method .

Answer (score 4):

Do you test a method that stores some data into a database?

Short answer - Yes.

If *all* it does is take a [strongly typed] value and write it into a database, then you could argue that it will get [thoroughly] tested by the *rest* of the application.

If the method does any kind of *validation* on the supplied value, then you *absolutely* need to test it.